# What is the word for "play your part"?

Tags: definitions

The closest that I can see is 出し合う. Is there something better to express doing what you are expected to do in a pre-arranged situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

「自分の役目を果たす」「自分の役割を果たす」「自分の務めを果たす」

Comment: Do any of these fit in  a military context? Are they relevant for an ad hoc circumstance?

Comment: I think these are the most general ways to say "play one's role/part", or "perform one's duties". You could use any of them in a military context, but 自分の任務を果たす (lit. complete one's mission) might sound a bit better? (任務=mission)